# How to get mismatch ratio of two images with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, image-comparison, resemblejs

I am looking for faster alternatives to [ResembleJS](https://github.com/Huddle/Resemble.js?files=1) for image comparison.

So far I am able to create the similar output image like ResembleJS does:

```
convert fullhd.jpg \
\( -clone 0 fullhd2.jpg -compose difference -composite \
-threshold 1% -fill purple -opaque white -transparent black \) \
-compose over -composite fullhd_compare.jpg
```

But in ResembleJS you can get this kind of output:

```
{ isSameDimensions: true,
  dimensionDifference: { width: 0, height: 0 },
  misMatchPercentage: '0.73',
  analysisTime: 143,
  getDiffImage: [Function] }
```

Is there a way to get those especially the misMatchPercantage ?

Comment: Have you tried the `compare` utility that ships with ImageMagick?

Comment: yes what I get is this: compare: image widths or heights differ `fullhd.jpg'

Comment: What sort of images are you comparing - do you have sample images please?